# How to maximize the odds of getting a selection correct given a shuffled deck of cards?

Tags: probability, sampling, random-variable, combinatorics

Here's the situation:

You are playing a game, in which the object of this game is to obtain the highest score possible. You have a list or array of values from 1 to 100 (we will visualize these as a deck of cards for simplicity) which has been randomized (shuffled). You are then asked to select a card from the top. After seeing its value, you are asked to guess whether the next card in the list will be higher or lower than the current card, and if you get it right you will gain a point, if you get it wrong you will lose a point. The next card then becomes the base card to go off of for the next higher/lower selection, and the previous card is completely removed from the game. This goes on until there are no cards left to compare.

Now for the first selection this would appear to be pretty simple, just select higher or lower based off of the number of cards remaining in the deck that are greater or less than the value. However, do all of the following selections still only follow this simple rule? I'm wondering if there are any probability rules that say two consecutive higher or lower outcomes lower the chances of the next value being the same. For example, let's say I initially draw a 16. The next card is a 21, so the outcome is higher. The next card is a 29 so the outcome is higher. Now even though I have a 29, and it would appear that selecting higher gives the greatest chance of being right, is there anything that decreases the probability of it being higher again or is it still just simply (number of cards greater than) / (total number of cards)?

Comment: Such a beautiful example to shape your coding skills a gain an insight from simulation!

Comment: That's basically what I'm trying to do here. I have a solution already that uses the simple probability example I listed, but it's been about 6 years since my last statistics course so I'm pretty rusty on that side of things lol I'm curious if there's a more accurate probability model out there or if what I currently have already is the most accurate.

Comment: You have complete information since whenever you draw the next card you know all the numbers that are left and the order is random. So you just compute the # of cards greater then the one drawn and divide by the # of remaining cards. If the number is greater than 1/2 pick higher.  If the number is less than 1/2 pick lower.  If the proportion equal 1/2 there is no advantage to pick higher or lower so you can decide at random.  On each draw this strategy maximizes the probability of gaining a point.  Your objective is to maximize the expected number of points gained.

Comment: Keep in mind that on any draw there is a chance that you will not gain a point  unless all remaining cards are greater than the current one or are less than the current one. So you still need to show that the strategy is optimal in that it maximizes the expected score.

Comment: The answer to the question "does it matter if you have two correct guesses to go higher" does not matter. if the deck was just 4 cards, "A,2,3,4" and you saw the ace first, and correct said higher, and got the 2, again higher and got the three, the next guess is still the rule of count of H vs count of L cards (in this case guess higher again!)  (H=all cards that are higher, L=count of cards lower)